# Adversarial text generation with gradient clipping, still facing gradient explosion

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training an text generation model with Generative adversarial networks.
As a common method, I used `tf.clip_by_global_norm()` to avoid gradient problems. However, even I used gradient clipping, I am still facing gradient exploding problem with error caused by `tf.clip_by_global_norm()` function.
The document says: If `global_norm == infinity` then the entries in `t_list` are all set to `NaN` to signal that an error occurred.

I can hardly find the origin of problem with this situation since I believed that `tf.clip_by_global_norm` definitely avoid the gradient problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tf.clip_by_value? You could set clip_value_min to be -1 and the max to be 1.
If you're using an embedding matrix for your text, the embedding values shouldn't get larger than 1

Also as an aside, people have tried using GAN's for text generation, and the results aren't very good